# C: Can a too large stack lead to a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have recently debugged a very strange problem that caused a segmentation fault.

Basically, the problem went away after I have moved a couple of very large arrays that were declared as local variables to being global, which means as far as I know that I moved them from the stack to the heap space. Nothing else was changed. The segmentation fault itself appeared in very old and stable code that was also shared across other programs that did not experience any segmentation faults.

In total, these arrays were about 1.5 MB in size.

Is it possible that a too large stack can cause a segmentation fault by overwriting/messing up function pointers?

My feeling is that such a thing should be caught by the compiler, but I have absolutely no other way of explaining this behaviour.

The platform is Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: What does it say when you run it in the debugger - do you get a reasonable stack trace or do you just get a stack trace with one function in it?  Have you tried running with valgrind?

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow can definitively cause seg faults as well all sorts of  other strange bahaviour. Did you try to compile differently in order to have more stack space? What is your platform? Did you check that none of your array indexes are out of bounds? The fact your code was apparently stable does not exclude latter (see undefined behaviour)

Comment: Last I knew, the default main stack size (may differ for threads) was 1 MiB on Windows and 8 MiB on Linux and macOS. So, yes, arrays of 1.5 MB or 1.5 MiB will overrun the default stack on Windows and, if used with other large objects, on Linux and macOS.

Comment: @cup: gdb said: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7f6d18

Comment: @cup: This happened at the beginning of the (very old, very stable) function, so I see that as a dead end.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: In some of my tests the array was only declared and not used, so the index cannot be out of bounds there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack size of a program is limited, so declaring too many large arrays as local variables can cause a stack overflow.  What you did is a good way of handling the issue.

It's not something that compilers typically check for, as stack size is controlled at run time by the OS, for example `ulimit -s` or `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` on Linux systems.  The [man page for `getrlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) states the following regarding stack size:

> RLIMIT_STACK
>
> The maximum size of the process stack, in bytes. Upon reaching this
>   limit, a SIGSEGV signal is generated. To handle this signal, a process
>   must employ an alternate signal stack (sigaltstack(2)).

So on Linux, the size of the stack is a run-time setting, and overrunning the stack explicitly causes a segmentation violation.

Comment: Stack size controlled by the OS? Or by the run-time code of the program? Normally the stack is set-up at program start and the size won't change dynamically (by the OS). Pages may be enabled or swapped, but that is another matter.

Comment: Programs can request stack sizes in the executable file. This is typically set with a linker option. So the Linux resource limits are not the only method of control. I do not have the details at hand.

Comment: @RolandSeuhs The function with the large arrays may not be enough by itself to blow up the stack, but can get it close enough that a few more small function calls can push it over the edge.